# При чтении файла первое слово считывается неправильно

Tags: java

Дано задание: считать текстовый файл и найти в нем слово, которое встречается реже всего. Возникает ошибка с тем, что первое слово в строке считывается неправильно, отдельно от копий, при попытке сравнить его методом .equals() с другим абсолютно идентичным словом - получаю результат false.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    rarestWord("D:/testfile.txt");
}

static void rarestWord(String filename){
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        //чтение построчно
        String str;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] slova = str.split(" ");
            for (int i =0;i<slova.length;i++){
                list.add(slova[i]);
            }
        }

        //поиск нужного элемента
        Map<Integer, String> wordsmap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

        for (String thing : list) {
            wordsmap.put(Collections.frequency(list, thing), thing);
        }
        System.out.println(((TreeMap<Integer, String>) 
wordsmap).firstEntry());


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка:"+e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте посмотрел текстовый файл шестнадцатеричным редактором, чтобы проверить его на наличие [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) в начале файла. Если BOM есть - то это скорее всего и является причиной.